# VSCode is unable to build the intellisense

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using vscode for c/c++ development. VSCode use to work very well but recently I have noticed that the IntelliSense is not working. When I was the "update database"(as in the attached picture) icon is always on. Any suggestion on how to get this to work? [image]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the extention? If I [search with Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vscode+c%2B%2B+%22updating+intellisense%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), I get a lot of hits. Have you looked at these?

Comment: Deleting the cache is another thing to try

Comment: In my experience, Intellisense stops working when you have opened your solution or project in different Visual Studio instances.

Answer (score 0):

For this question you disable the extension and enable it for a try. Or there maybe something struck.